# Azure Redis Cache

Tags: azure, cache, redis

Is it possible to create Azure Redis Cache using API and to create primary and secondary key by my own ( I want to create keys and then to forward these key to Redis Cache)? So basically I want to skip automatically generated key on Azure Redis Cache.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible to generate your own keys, they will always be generated by the platform.
I'm curious as to why you want to generate your own? What are you trying to achieve?